# How to get the Function Output in the Multiple Columns of select Query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to create output from the query for which the data for multiple columns must be fetched by a function call. The Function format is :

```
F_TRAVEL_CLAIM_AMOUNT_COUNT(CLM_ID NUMBER,SYS_ID  NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
(output example: 5000,0,5000,5000,0,5000)
```

below is the query snippet in which I want to get the column B,C,D,E,F,G values from the function based on the delimiter comma from the function output

```
select PC.A,B,C,D,E,F,G,PC.H FROM PT_CLAIM PC

Sample Values from Function output: 
B=5000, C=0, D=5000, E=5000,F=0,G=5000.
```

Also, the function uses the input parameters from PT_CLAIM table.

Comment: One options is to use `TABLE` functions : https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions#table_functions

Comment: @KaushikNayak thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend Barbaros showed how you can return a sys_refcursor. And I show you how parse it via sql:

```
create or replace function f_travel_claim_amount_count( i_sql varchar2 )
return sys_refcursor is
    v_result sys_refcursor;  
begin
    open v_result for i_sql;
    return v_result;
end;
/

select *
from xmltable(
'ROWSET/ROW'
passing 
    xmltype(f_travel_claim_amount_count('select rownum r, chr(ascii(dummy) - level + 1) d from dual connect by level <= 5'))
columns 
r number           path 'R',
d varchar2(1 char) path 'D'
);

         R D
---------- -
         1 X
         2 W
         3 V
         4 U
         5 T
```

Btw looking at the topic starter example I think xmltype is more better than varchar2 data type for a set of reasons (varchar2 is a size-limited and xml is structured).

```
-- create your function return xmltype
create or replace function drop_me(p_num number) return xmltype as
v_xml xmltype;
begin
    select 
    xmlelement(root, 
      xmlagg(
        xmlelement(record,
          xmlelement(r, rownum),
          xmlelement(d, chr(ascii(dummy) - rownum + 1))
                   )
            order by rownum)
               )
    into v_xml
    from dual
    connect by level <= p_num;

    return v_xml;
end;
/

-- call it
select drop_me(4)
from dual;

-- parse xml
select *
from xmltable(
'ROOT/RECORD'
passing drop_me(5)
columns 
r number           path 'R',
d varchar2(1 char) path 'D'
);
         R D
---------- -
         1 X
         2 W
         3 V
         4 U
         5 T
```

Answer (score 0):

you have mentioned that - 'values from the function based on the delimiter comma from the function output'
so my understanding was that function output should return values by delimiter??
if that the case, then we can just concatenate the required values then we can return as varchar2, and in the main procedure we can have that value and either it can be processed as a whole, or splitted to individual values and processed then

```
create or replace function sample_func return varchar2
is
l_val varchar2(4000);
begin
select name||','||age||','||place into l_val from sample_tbl where rownum=1;
return l_val;
end;

declare
l_main_val varchar2(4000);
l_ind_val varchar2(4000);
begin
l_main_val:=sample_func;
dbms_output.put_line('function return:'||l_main_val);
dbms_output.put_line('individual values');
loop
exit when instr(l_main_val,',')=0;
l_ind_val:= substr(l_main_val,0,instr(l_main_val,',')-1);
dbms_output.put_line(l_ind_val);
l_main_val:=substr(l_main_val,NVL(instr(l_main_val,','),length(l_main_val))+1);
exit when l_main_val is NULL;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(l_main_val);
end;

-- output 

Statement processed.
function return:hulk,45,marvel
individual values
hulk
45
marvel
```

advantage of using concatenated return value, is that it can be directly used in standalone select query:

```
select sample_func from dual;
-- output

SAMPLE_FUNC
hulk,45,marvel
```

other than this we can define record type or table type as per business needs and get it done.
but if record or table type is used, it can't be used in standalone select queries.

the inputs can be passed to the function through IN parameters

Answer (score 0):

if the number of values are limited, You can try and split the string into several values and store them in variables (B,C,D...).

Then, you can just do the same whatever you have tried:

```
select PC.A,B,C,D,E,F,G,PC.H FROM PT_CLAIM PC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys_refcursor` as the returning type to get the results column by column

```
SQL> create or replace function F_TRAVEL_CLAIM_AMOUNT_COUNT( i_sql varchar2 )
                  return sys_refcursor is
    v_result sys_refcursor;  
begin
    open v_result for i_sql;
    return v_result;
end;

SQL> declare
  v_result  sys_refcursor;
  v_sql     varchar2(4000):='select PC.A,B,C,D,E,F,G,PC.H FROM PT_CLAIM PC';
begin
  v_result := f_travel_claim_amount_count(v_sql);
end;
```